# Undefined reference problems with libusb

Tags: python, libraries, dynamic-linking

I'm trying to use [pyuvc](https://github.com/pupil-labs/pyuvc) module which depends on [libuvc](https://github.com/ktossell/libuvc) which depends on libusb. However, when I try to import `uvc` in python, I get

```
ImportError: /usr/local/lib/libuvc.so.0: undefined symbol: libusb_handle_events_completed
```

As I googled around, I saw many people encountered this problem but nothing worked. Usually it was an issue of having wrong version of libusb installed, and I guess something similar is happening here too. I wanted to just remove all libusb related packages and reinstall them, but I got a scary warning that it could destroy my system.

I'm using Debian 8 (Jessie)

I have no idea how to continue, please help

Comment: It's clearly version dependency problem. libuvc uses libusb but libusb doesn't have function or variable with name `libusb_handle_events_completed`. You should update `libusb`.

Comment: @YurijGoncharuk I tried running `apt install libusb-1.0-0-dev` but I probably have an old version somewhere that's still there. How can I locate that version? And remove it without breaking the system?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just in case anyone else has this issue: apparently, pyuvc requires their own fork of libuvc found at https://github.com/pupil-labs/libuvc, not the official version that's linked in their readme. To make sure I have their version installed, I did a `sudo rm /usr/local/lib/libuvc*` and then proceeded with instructions listed in the link above.

Comment: Um... If you previously had `pyuvc` installed from you ordinary package manager, don't you have a very broken package now?

Comment: It's not even available via pip: https://github.com/pupil-labs/pyuvc/issues/39